# How would you reuse an item from another page in a stacked widget - pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

If you have a stacked widget with two pages, and one label that you want on both pages, how would you go about doing this without re-defining it with a different variable name. I'm not actually sure if this is possible, but since I have a pretty large project, I'm trying to make my code as small as I can.

An example would be like this.

```
...
self.firstPage = QtGui.QWidget()
self.firstPage.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("firstPage"))

self.testLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.firstPage)
self.testLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 921, 91))
self.testLabel.setText(_fromUtf8("this is just a test label"))
self.testLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("testLabel"))

self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.firstPage)


self.secondPage = QtGui.QWidget()
...
self.stackedWdiget.addWidget(self.secondPage)
```

Say I wanted to add testLabel to the secondPage in the stackedWidget. Is the only way to get testLabel onto the second page to re-define it as say testLabel-2 and then re-add all of it's settings.

Comment: literally unplugging the control from one page and plugging it into the other, on the fly, would seem to avail... C-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my experience, that's not possible. Because the `QLabel` class inherits `QWidget`, so you can add a widget inside only one  other widget. The objects not inheriting `QWidget` can be used for as many widgets as you want. For example, one object of `QIcon`or `QFont` can be used for many widgets to set their icon or font.

If you need *labels* inside more than one *widget*, you need to create separate *labels* for each *widget*.

**UPDATE:**

If you have lot of widgets to create, you need to define a separate method to create objects of that widget:

```
...
def createPage(self, objName):
    page = QtGui.QWidget()
    page.setObjectName(_fromUtf8(objName))
    return page

def createLabel(self, parent, objName, text):
    label = QtGui.QLabel(parent)
    label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 921, 91))
    label.setText(_fromUtf8(text))
    label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8(objName))
    return label

def setPages(self)
    self.firstPage = self.createPage("firstPage")
    # call self.createLabel and add label to self.firstPage
    self.secondPage = self.createPage("secondPage")
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.firstPage)
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.secondPage)
...
```

You now can create as many labels as you want without repeating your code. This is good practice to create separate methods for code that you think will be repeated in the application. In your case, call `createLabel` method, it will return an object, put that object inside any widget as you need. Also you can save the objects of labels as you saved objects of pages to refer to them later in the code.

Comment: Yeah, but I have a multiple pages, and theres maybe 20 items in each page that are exactly the same, so I was kind of hoping that I could reuse the code to save _alot_ of space.

Comment: Ah, that's an approach I hadn't thought of. Thanks that's what i was looking for.